# Embedding model variables in textarea with Angualar.js

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to embed some model variables in a textarea input so that client side changes in one field populate in another input. I have tried the following (and googled a bit) but I cant get it to work........

```
 <textarea ng-model="event.message" required ngMaxlength="{255}" ngMinlength="{10}" ng-init="event.message='Hi, {{event.name}} today at {{event.time}}. Reply with in to join or out if you cant make it. Thanks.'" class="form-control">
                    Hi, {{event.name}} today at {{event.time}}. Reply with in to join or out if you cant make it. Thanks.
                </textarea>
```

In this example event.name is bound to another input but it does not show in the text area when changed.

Is there a way to get this to work?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JTH5G4?p=preview).

I think the main issue you were facing was within the `ng-init`:

```
ng-init="event.message='Hi, {{event.name}} today at {{event.time}}. Reply with in to join or out if you cant make it. Thanks.'"
```

Inside the `ng-init` you don't need to interpolate `{{ }}` because it is already running in a JavaScript context.

So you can change it to this:

```
ng-init="event.message='Hi, ' + event.name + ' today at ' + event.time + '. Reply with in to join or out if you cant make it. Thanks.'"
```

Also, if you are using `ng-init` there is no reason to also have content inside the `<textarea>`, it will only get replaced wholesale anyway.